# "My dreams were ---" what?

Tags: single-word-requests

In an essay, I need to imply that a certain incident reduced my chances at something (my dream).

"My dreams were _______" - not crushed completely, but partially. So what word or phrase could fill the blanks?

I thought of "My dreams were **worn thin** when this happened". Does worn thin work fine or not?

Comment: *not crushed completely, but partially* suggests *dented*

Comment: Quelled, squashed, smothered, dashed, dead? How dark and poetic do we want to take this?

Comment: @Julia The tricky part is he *doesn't* want the defeat to be final; he wants to describe  a disheartening but *temporary* setback.

Comment: Deflated, perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps his dreams were subdued, shaken, disheartened, or cowed?

Comment: @DanBron Yup, that's exactly what I mean; words like shaken and dented like suggester above.

Comment: How about the rather simple *damaged*?

Comment: *Compromised*: ["To reduce the quality, value, or degree of something, such as one's ideals."](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compromised)

Answer (score 5):

### **Verbatim** translation/replacement for the OP's "quote"/phrase:

> "...my dream was **diminished**."
>     "...my dreams were **diminished**."

---

### More **ACCURATE**

The true concept behind the OP's question is not of the dream(s) being crushed/less ambitious, but rather the *CHANCES* or *HOPES* of it/them becoming a reality/successful:

1. **1 chance/hope** for **1 dream** to manifest:

   > - "...my dream's chance/hope of success was **diminished**"
   > - "...my hope for my dream's success was **diminished**"
   > - "...my dream's chance of success had now been **diminished**"
   > - "...the chance of my dream succeeding was **diminished**"
   > - "...the chance that my dream would succeed was **diminished**"
   > - "...the chance of my dream succeeding was **diminishing**"
2. **1 chance/hope** for **multiple dreams** to manifest all at once:

   > - "...my dreams' chance/hope of success was **diminished**"
   > - "...my hope for my dreams' success was **diminished**"
   > - "...my dreams' chance of success had now been **diminished**"
   > - "...the chance of my dreams succeeding was **diminished**"
   > - "...the chance that my dreams would succeed was **diminished**"
   > - "...the chance of my dreams succeeding was **diminishing**"
3. **multiple chances/hopes** for **1 dream** to manifest:

   > - "...my dream's chances/hopes of success were **diminished**"
   > - "...my hopes for my dream's success were **diminished**"
   > - "...my dream's chances of success had now been **diminished**"
   > - "...the chances of my dream succeeding were **diminished**"
   > - "...the chances that my dream would succeed were **diminished**"
   > - "...the chances of my dream succeeding were **diminishing**"
4. **multiple chances/hopes** for **multiple dreams** to manifest all at once:

   > - "...my dreams' chances/hopes of success were **diminished**"
   > - "...my hopes for my dreams' success were **diminished**"
   > - "...my dreams' chances of success had now been **diminished**"
   > - "...the chances of my dreams succeeding were **diminished**"
   > - "...the chances that my dreams would succeed were **diminished**"
   > - "...the chances of my dreams succeeding were **diminishing**"

Comment: I disagree, to diminish something is to reduce and unless stated otherwise,  carried connotation that it is permanent. Rather, OP implies a word that takes into account that his dreams were still there (i.e. not diminished) but rather hindered or impeded in a way.

Comment: The OP him/herself states nothing re: permanence. And even if he she did diminished does not imply permits it just means to reduce which is **literally*j what the OP is asking - "reduced my chances at something" - please remove ur down vote - I'd appreciate it

Comment: I think diminished is better than some of the other answers.

Comment: "reduced my chances at something (my dream)." I feel the word diminished is not sympathetic to the idea that the dream in focus was now harder to attained. If his dreams were diminished, they just got smaller and less ambitious.

Comment: @silenceislife truth is in order to convey that... it would have to be "...my dreams' chances of success were/had been diminished"

Comment: @silenceislife notice my additional variations in my edits.  If we are being true to the OP, then it would be #1 - which although I agree with you, it would more *exact* to the wording the OP used in his Question.  However, if we're trying to convey a truer meaning of the phrase, I agree that it's his changes or hopes that were diminished.

Comment: @FlakDiNenno Yes precisely what you wrote above now seems more sensible with the additional information provided +1

Answer (score 4):

My dreams were [dampened](http://citylimits.org/2002/09/01/firsthand-a-cold-welcome/)

**dampen**: to dull or deaden; depress

Alternately,

My dreams were [dimmed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dim?s=t)

**dim**: make dim or dimmer

Answer (score 2):

The idiom **dash someone's hopes** is an idiom that express a similar situation as the one mentioned by the OP. The Free Dictionary says: *[Fig. to ruin someone's hopes; to put an end to someone's dreams or aspirations.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dash+hopes)*

I have heard people say that their dreams were dashed, to say that a  strong desire was thwarted by someone or something. It doesn't necessarily mean that the same dream cannot be resurrected at a later date.

> My dreams were **dashed**

Alternatively, the OP could rephrase his sentence and say

> My dreams **suffered a minor setback** when…

suffer from a setback: [*to have a minor or temporary failure*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/setback)

Comment: Upvoted, but despite your reassurances, I do worry that *dashed* shares *crushed*'s original flaw: it is final. After all, if you *dash* your saucer against the tile .... well there is very little hope of it *being resurrected at a later date*.

Comment: To dash someone's hopes is to ruin them...not what the OP wants.

Comment: @michael_timofeev what about the second suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try *[tarnished](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tarnish)* or *[obnibulated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obnubilate)*

neither are extreme in the sense that something is completely lost, which it seems is what you are trying to avoid. Both of these words are synonyms for "to cast a gloom over" which it sounds like has happened to your dreams.

You may also try *[impoverished](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/impoverish)* which is another non-extreme and has to do with "making poor or poor in quality"

Answer (score -2):

My dreams were *impeded*

impeded:

> delay or prevent (someone or something) by obstructing them; hinder.

alternatively,

My dreams were hindered

hindered:

> make it difficult for (someone) to do something or for (something) to happen.